# Scroll overflowed div to vertical center on element in Angular (5)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a custom table consisting of divs using the flex layout rendered via angular like such:

```
<div class="tbody">
  <div class="tr"
       *ngFor="let ask of asks">
    <div class="td centered red">{{ask.price | number: '1.8-8'}}</div>
    <div class="td centered">{{ask.amount | number: '1.7-7'}}</div>
    <div class="td centered">{{ask.sum | number: '1.7-7'}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr"> this should be in the middle</div>
  <div class="tr"
       *ngFor="let bid of bids">
    <div class="td centered green">{{bid.price | number: '1.8-8'}}</div>
    <div class="td centered">{{bid.amount | number: '1.7-7'}}</div>
    <div class="td centered">{{bid.sum | number: '1.7-7'}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the "table" to center on the middle `tr` (see above excerpt) when it's rendered.

This is similar to how, for example, the Order Book looks on GDAX (see below screenshot). As you can tell from the scroll bar on the right, this is a much longer overflowed div that is currently in the middle. It is rendered in the middle to the user.

[image: example from gdax.com]

If the above is impossible, an intermediate workaround could be to center the entire div (assuming that the two datasets will be of similar length). I have also been unable to find any solution to this, so if anyone knows please feel free to submit as an answer.

Comment: You mean in the middle vertically?

Comment: @Vega correct, the middle vertically. Imagine you have a vertically scrolling table, such as in the picture above. I'd like that to be centered vertically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@ViewChild` decorator to get a reference to the element and set the `scrollTop` property.

First add some template references to the elements so they can be captured using `@ViewChild`.

```
<div class="tbody" #scrollMe>
    ...
    <div class="tr" #middle>...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Then in your component implementation declare the `@ViewChild` element references and calculate the correct `scrollTop` value when the component is initialized.

```
export class ExampleComponent {

  @ViewChild('scrollMe') scrollElem: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('middle') middle: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    var elem = this.scrollElem.nativeElement;
    var middleOffset = this.middle.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    elem.scrollTop = middleOffset - (elem.offsetHeight / 2);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake! I had to make a few minor adjustments to make this work in my case, but your answer pointed me in the right direction. If anyone else is having the same issue, I had to put the code to center the table inside of an `window.setTimeout()` block after the data has been loaded such that it centers after the template has been rendered. I also had to factor in the offset of the `scrollElem` itself and the height of the `middleOffset` too to ensure absolute center. The following is my final code:

Comment: `window.setTimeout(() => {... elem.scrollTop = middleElem.offsetTop - elem.offsetTop - (elem.offsetHeight / 2) + (middleElem.offsetHeight / 2)})`